# Angular2 - unit testing with karma, system module option

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

I don't understand this situation:
I'm working on a ng2 boilerplate with unit testing. (Repo: https://github.com/sandhaka/typescriptang2boilerplate)

When I changed module option from commonjs to system in tsconfig.js, karma is not working anymore ... it return with this empty error:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "originalErr": {}
  }
```

I don't know how resolve this... there aren't any error detail.
Someone have some idea?
thanks.

Comment: I get the same error when I try to import my own component. I didn't fix it yet.

Comment: i had the same problem for karma testing. for me i had to make sure the casing of the file name is exactly what you intend. for example, i had a file name 'Person.ts' (capital P), and i just changed it to 'person.ts' (lowercase p) then the problem went away with karma.